# Objective-C Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSMutableArray from NSArray

Tags: objective-c, apigee-baas

I have this code

```
      [[self.client dataClient] getEntities:@"book" query:nil
                    completionHandler:^(ApigeeClientResponse *result)                          {
                        if (result.transactionState ==kApigeeClientResponseSuccess) {
                            _objects = result.response[@"entities"];
                        } else {
                            _objects = @[]; //"Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSMutableArray from NSArray"
                        }
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                    }];
```

It shows me error  "Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSMutableArray from NSArray"

Comment: So assign then `[NSMutableArray array]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

**`_objects` is implemented in `NSArray` and returns an `NSArray` even when called on an `NSMutableArray`.**

assign `[NSMutableArray array];`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assing a `NSArray` (`@[]`) to a variable of type `NSMutableArray`.

Replace:

```
 _objects = @[];
```

with:

```
_objects = @[].mutableCopy;
```

Even you do not mention an error in the first if clause, you have to replace this also.

```
_objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:result.response[@"entities"]];
```